# Create a list to Plot from a list returned by Solve

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, map

I have a list of 8 items the form:

```
L={{v -> 0.015876}, {v -> 0.214969}, {v -> 0.293763}, {v -> 0.78181}, {v -> 1.8144}, {v -> 1.8144}, {v -> 7.63829}, {v -> 7.68563}}
```

From this list I would like to create the list:

```
{{f(v1),v1},...,{f(v8),v8}}
```

in a nice way (I can do it with a for loop but I wonder if there is (as always) a good way of doing it). 
$v1,\ldots v8$ correspond to the numerical values of the original list.

I would like to create a function $g$ of two variables $a,v$ and which return ${f(v/.a),v/.a)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the intermediate function which will take the data from your list and apply your function `f`:

```
g={f@#[[1,2]],#[[1,2]]}&;
g/@L
```

Output:

{{f[0.015876], 0.015876}, {f[0.214969], 0.214969}, {f[0.293763], 
  0.293763}, {f[0.78181], 0.78181}, {f[1.8144], 1.8144}, {f[1.8144], 
  1.8144}, {f[7.63829], 7.63829}, {f[7.68563], 7.68563}}

UPD:

```
ll=v/.L;
g={f@#,#}&;
g/@ll
```

gives you the same result.